# Simulating hand position with Xtion pro live

Tags: c#

I am studying C# Programming and Kinect sensors programming (I am quite a 
newbie in both C# language and Kinect). I am trying to use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to write applications using sensors of Xtion Pro Live to control robots. In my main form, there are 2 picturebox objects, 2 button object, 3 label and 3 textbox objects. One of the two picturebox objects (pictureBox1) is to display the RGB camera. The other one  pictureBox2) is to simulate the hand positions in 2D (x and y coordinates) graphics. One of the two buttons (button1) is to initialize Xtion Pro Live and to show RGB camera on picturebox1, and to simulate hand positions on picturebox2. The other one (button2) is to exit the program. The three labels, label1, label2, label3, and the three textboxes, textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 are used to show 3 coordinates of the hand.

This is my code in Form1.cs:

```
using OpenNI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HandTracking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const string path = @"C:/Vu/Kinect/Data/SamplesConfig.xml";
        public bool run;
        public Thread thread;
        public Bitmap bitmap;
        public Context context;
        public ScriptNode node;
        public ImageGenerator image;
        public DepthGenerator depth;
        public GestureGenerator gesture;
        public HandsGenerator hand;
        public Queue<Point3D> handpoint = new Queue<Point3D>();
        public const int maxpoint = 30;
        enum GestureStatus
        {
            Unrecognized, Progress, Recognized
        }
        private GestureStatus gesstatus = GestureStatus.Unrecognized;
        enum HandsStatus
        {
            Untracked, Create, Update
        }
        private HandsStatus handstatus = HandsStatus.Untracked;
        public Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
        public Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Magenta);
        public Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 20);
        public PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            this.pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button1.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                context = Context.CreateFromXmlFile(path, out node);
                image = context.FindExistingNode(NodeType.Image) as ImageGenerator;
                if (image == null)
                    throw new Exception(context.GlobalErrorState);
                depth = context.FindExistingNode(NodeType.Depth) as DepthGenerator;
                if (depth == null)
                    throw new Exception(context.GlobalErrorState);
                depth.AlternativeViewpointCapability.SetViewpoint(image);
                    gesture = context.FindExistingNode(NodeType.Gesture) as     GestureGenerator;
                if (gesture == null)
                   throw new Exception(context.GlobalErrorState);
                gesture.AddGesture("RaiseHand");
                gesture.GestureRecognized += new     EventHandler<GestureRecognizedEventArgs>(GestureRecognized);
                gesture.GestureProgress += new EventHandler<GestureProgressEventArgs>    (GestureProgress);
                hand = context.FindExistingNode(NodeType.Hands) as HandsGenerator;
                if (hand == null)
                    throw new Exception(context.GlobalErrorState);
                hand.HandCreate += new EventHandler<HandCreateEventArgs>(HandCreate);
                hand.HandUpdate += new EventHandler<HandUpdateEventArgs>(HandUpdate);
                context.StartGeneratingAll();
                MapOutputMode map = image.MapOutputMode;
                bitmap = new Bitmap((int)map.XRes, (int)map.YRes,     System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                run = true;
                thread = new Thread(CallThread);
                thread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        public void GestureRecognized(object sender, GestureRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            gesstatus = GestureStatus.Recognized;
            hand.StartTracking(e.EndPosition);
        }

        public void GestureProgress(object sender, GestureProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            gesstatus = GestureStatus.Progress;
        }

        public void HandCreate(object sender, HandCreateEventArgs e)
        {
            handstatus = HandsStatus.Create;
        }

        public void HandUpdate(object sender, HandUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            handstatus = HandsStatus.Update;
            handpoint.Enqueue(e.Position);
        }
        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to quit?", "Confirm",     MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    run = false;
                    if (thread != null)
                        thread.Join();
                    this.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                 }
            }
        }

        public void CallThread()
        {
            try
            {
                while (run)
                {
                    Data();
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                    pictureBox2.Invalidate();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        public unsafe void Data()
        {
            context.WaitAndUpdateAll();
            ImageMetaData imd = image.GetMetaData();
            lock (this)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,     System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                byte* dstp = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer();
                byte* imstp = (byte*)image.ImageMapPtr.ToPointer();
                for (int i = 0; i < imd.DataSize; i += 3, dstp += 3, imstp += 3)
                {
                    dstp[0] = imstp[2];
                    dstp[1] = imstp[1];
                    dstp[2] = imstp[0];
                }
                bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
                if (handpoint.Count != 0)
                {
                    Point3D start =     depth.ConvertRealWorldToProjective(handpoint.Peek());
                    foreach (Point3D hpoint in handpoint)
                    {
                        Point3D pt = depth.ConvertRealWorldToProjective(hpoint);
                        HandPosition(start);
                        start = pt;
                    }
                }
                string mess = "Gesture: RaiseHand" + " ,Status:" + gesstatus.ToString()     + "\n" + "Hand: " + handstatus.ToString();
                PicDraw(bitmap, mess);
            }
        }

        public void HandPosition(Point3D pt)
        {
            try
            {
                float a,b,c;
                string handx, handy, handz;
                a=pt.X;
                b=pt.Y;
                c=pt.Z;
                handx = a.ToString();
                handy = b.ToString();
                handz = c.ToString();
                Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
                g.FillEllipse(brush, a - 5, b - 5, 20, 20);
                textBox1.Text = handx;
                textBox2.Text = handy;
                textBox3.Text = handz;
                g.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        public void PicDraw(Bitmap bmap, string me)
        {
            try
            {
                Graphics g;
                pictureBox1.Image = bmap;
                g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                g.DrawString(me, font, brush, point);
                g.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code in Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HandTracking
{
    static class Program
    {
        ........
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Text = "Hand Tracking";
            f1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Application.Run(f1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the program many times, each time different errors are thrown: InvalidOperationException not handled; Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on; Object is currently in use elsewhere.
  I don't know whether the way I pass parameters at: HandPosition(start) and PicDraw(bitmap, mess) were correct. Any problem will come out if I use HandPosition(start) to control a robot? Can anybody show me my mistakes and help me correct the progam?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access a WinForms control on a thread other than the UI thread.  It is being done from the thread you are creating with `Thread.Start`.

A much better technique for Windows Forms is to use the BackgroundWorker approach (if you are using .NET 4, Task Parallel Library is very nice).  With BackgroundWorker, you send the thread off to do some work, and it gives the UI thread updates, sending back any objects of your choice.  Since you are newer to C#, BackgroundWorker is the right choice because it is simple to use, and there is tons of documentation on it if you get stuck.

On the UI thread, you just take those updates, and then update your WinForms controls from the UI thread.  Problem fixed.

To learn more about BackgroundWorker, Google it, or you can start here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: TO elaborate a bit, you will instantiate a BackgroundWorker from within your button click handler, give it a method for it to execute, and define some other methods that get called when the background worker finishes, and when there is progress to report.  Then, in your CallThread, Data, HandPosition, PicDraw, and other methods running on that thread, just send a progress update to the BackgroundWorker, and handle it in the callback methods you define.    Make sure to get all references to WinForms controls out of the methods that are running on the new thread.

Comment: onemancat, Thank you very much for your help. I will learn more about BackgroundWorker.

Comment: You're welcome.  Can you do me the kindness of marking my solution as the answer?  That's one thing that makes people want to try their best to answer questions.